# Bootstrap 3 datatimepicker clears my value from textbox

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I have problem with bootstrap datetimepicker.

When my datatimepicker is active (javascript works), the textfield is empty.

When I will change of id for div with id="ada" and my datatimepicker isn't active, the data is printed correctly. It it MWE for my code (generated by asp.net mvc with razor).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/respond.js"></script>

    <script src="Scripts/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date datetimepickerbutton' id="ada">
                <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field DataPoczatku must be a date." data-val-required="The DataPoczatku field is required." id="katalog_DataPoczatku" name="katalog.DataPoczatku" type="date" value="2015-03-01 00:00:00" />

                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ada').datetimepicker();
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Somebody have idea how to keep the value of textbox with active datapicker?

https://jsfiddle.net/abbdzpg2/

Comment: Make a working fiddle please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give a date format YYYY-MM-DD in your input value and set a format value in your settings too. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zde4gjL5/2/). Is this the result you wanted?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ada').datetimepicker({
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date datetimepickerbutton' id="ada">
        <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field DataPoczatku must be a date." data-val-required="The DataPoczatku field is required." id="katalog_DataPoczatku" name="katalog.DataPoczatku" type="date" value="2015-03-01" /> <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a default date for the timepicker, you need to do this in the jQuery script, rather than setting a value. This is because the add on overrides the default behaviour of the form control.

```
var date = new Date('2015-03-01');

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ada').datetimepicker({
        defaultDate: date
    });
});
```

Comment: Is here nothing any option? I'm using it in my asp.net mvc with razor, and my view is binding with model... Here is easy example but I'm using list of objects and every object has minimum two dates...

Comment: As default, BS3 Datetimepicker is empty. If you remove the default value of the form-control, it will be empty. Is that what you want?